# Density of a subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I've been trying with a colleague but we could not come to a solution. The problem is as follows:

> Let $M$ be a subset of a Hilbert space $H$, and let $v,w\in H$. Suppose that $\langle v,x\rangle=\langle w,x\rangle$ for all $x\in M$ implies $v=w$. If this holds for all $v,w\in H$, show that $M$ is total in $H$.

**Note**: this is exercise 10 of Section 3.6 of Kreyszig's book *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*.

`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want "$((M\subset H) \wedge ( \forall (v,w)\in H\times H (\langle v,x\rangle = \langle w,x\rangle \forall x\in M) \Rightarrow (v=w)))\implies (M \text{ total in } H) $", yes?

Comment: yes, Might you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not versed in functional analysis yet so no, but if no one answers for a while I'll try to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is not total in $H$, then $M^\perp\neq\left\{0\right\}$. Let $v\in M^\perp$, $v\neq 0$. Then $v$ and $-v$ are distinct elements of $H$ but for all $x\in M$, $\langle v,x\rangle=0=\langle-v,x\rangle$. This solves (the contrapositive of) the exercise.

Comment: Because it takes v , -v H ?

Comment: Because it takes v , -v in  H ?